# Sublime Text - Any way to see definition of a method from standard C library?

Tags: c, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I don't know whether it's a stupid question. But here it is: In Sublime Text I haven't found any way to see the definition/documentation of a C/C++ method, no matter it comes from my own project or from system library. "Go To Definition" simply doesn't do anything. This is especially inconvenient when I'm reading some code which uses a bunch of std library stuffs which I don't necessarily recall at first sight, such as `strloul`, `getopt`, in which case I have to look them up in terminal or online, inducing overhead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a plugin like ctags or cscope

Comment: Minor point of terminology: you have headers for the standard C library functions which provide *declarations*, not definitions. It may be possible to install source packages to see definitions (depending on what libraries you're using), but they're not usually present by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install the [SublimeText CTags](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags) package.  Once installed and you have built your tags, you can put the cursor on the function of interest and (on OS X) type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>,<kbd>t</kbd> to jump to the method, wherever it might be located.  Typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>,<kbd>b</kbd> will bring you back to where you initiated the search from.

Example:

Cursor in the `print_matrix` function. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>,<kbd>t</kbd>

[image]

And it jumps to another file with the function definition:

[image]

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>,<kbd>b</kbd> takes you back again.

Comment: Thanks. When I searched the web with keywords like "Set Up Sublime C" etc I never got such information. Maybe a bit off-topic already, but is there also some plugins etc to automatically show errores in C/C++ source files before compiling, like all IDEs do? I searched for some but met various issues and they didn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't use it, but you might want to check out [SublimeLint](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/sublimelint).